# Including other template files in Handlbars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have a index.html file that i am using as my base file. I then want to separate sections of the site into smaller files to include in my base file. I am trying to do this with the navigation menu. I am using browserify to include the template files.

index.html

```
<body>
    <div id="nav-template"></div>
</body>
```

nav.handlebars

```
<script id="nav-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <p>This Is A Nav</p>
</script>
```

I then run handlebars nav.handlebars -f templates.js

app.js

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var Handlebars = require('handlebars');
var templates = require('./templates');

var template = Handlebars.templates['nav-template']
var html = template();

$('#nav-template').html(html);
```

I get nothing in my browser and no error.

Comment: Are you using browserify with handlebar transform ? (If so i think you should add it to the question)

Comment: Yes I am. Updated question thanks

Comment: when you `console.log(Handlebars.templates)`, do you have a `nav-template` key ? Also what is the results of `console.log(html)` ?

Answer (score 0):

nav.handlebars should be :

```
<p>This Is A Nav</p>
```

No need for the `script` markup when using external handlerbar files

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried both and get the same outcome